# image is bad with python in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a program in python:

```
import sys, random, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

# Preparing Pygame
size = width, height = 718, 502
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
framerate = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Cube')

#Peparing background
background_x = 0
background_y = 0
background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")


#Preparing Cube
cube_x = 100
cube_y = 200
cube_unscaled = pygame.image.load("cube.png")
cube = pygame.transform.smoothscale(cube_unscaled, (64, 64))

#Preparing Tubes
tube_x = 750
tube_y= 300
tube_unscaled = pygame.image.load("tube.png")
tube = pygame.transform.smoothscale(tube_unscaled, (125, 500))



# The main game loop
def exit_game():
        sys.exit()

while True:
        #Background
        screen.blit(background, (background_x,background_y))
        background_x = background_x+254.5
        screen.blit(cube,(cube_x, cube_y))
    #Tube
    tube_x = tube_x -.075
    screen.blit(tube,(tube_x, tube_y))
    # If exit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: exit_game()
    # If Space Key is presed
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
                    cube_y = cube_y-10
    #If Clicked
            elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                    cube_y = cube_y-10   
    framerate.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

I get this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKYRM.png

I have to boost `framerate.tick(60)` to `framerate.tick(700)` it looks a glichy. when I program the gravity the multiple images won't look good.

how can i fix the images been drawn multiple times before the screen updates?

Comment: Hmm I wonder what you're trying to make. :D

Comment: lol... after flappy birds closed i set off... but im changing the tube img.

Comment: The problem is how the cube looks, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I just needed to fill the screen with black before "bliting" it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cube_unscaled = pygame.image.load("cube.png").convert_alpha()
```

You shouldn't need to boost your FPS in such way, 60 is a good value.

Also, I like better this order for your main loop: check events, draw, update, tick.

I don't think it makes a difference to your problem, but I think it easier to understand that way.

```
while True:

    # If exit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: exit_game()

        # If Space Key is presed
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
            cube_y = cube_y-10

        #If Clicked
        elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                cube_y = cube_y-10

    #Background
    screen.blit(background, (background_x,background_y))
    background_x = background_x+254.5

    screen.blit(cube,(cube_x, cube_y))

    #Tube
    tube_x = tube_x -.075
    screen.blit(tube,(tube_x, tube_y))

    pygame.display.flip()
    framerate.tick(60)
```